# Which site to ask about identifying a (human) language / audio clip / song

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I found an MP3 on my hard drive of [a beautiful piece of music](http://www.eurosong.net/song.mp3) which I suspect I may have recorded myself... at some time in the past, before forgetting about it. Although it's mainly instrumental,  It contains singing in some kind of (Celtic?) language.

I want to identify it, however I have been unable to do so via song ID apps. I want to turn to crowdsourcing - and am therefore trying to find the most appropriate place to ask.

Browsing the SE sites, I can't decide which would be most suitable (if any). Could anyone advise where I might be able to post this? Thanks.

Comment: There aren’t any that would field this question. The obvious candidate is Linguistics.se, but they explicitly prohibit language identification questions. Basically identifying a specific thing is unlikely to help anyone but the asker, which is anathema to SS’s objectives of building a widely useable knowledgebase. Try reddit (or maybe Quora?).

Comment: I'm afraid [music](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does not permit identification questions either.

Comment: If you know the specific language, some of the language sites might accept listening questions (e.g. [German Language Beta](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions) does). But I don't know if that applies for language sites in general.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It doesn't apply to EL&U, we reject "listen" or "transcribe" questions, or anything which requires analysis of data which isn't in the text of the question. And I think reception is mixed at ELL. But generally speaking, smaller sites, having few questions and an appetite for more, tend to welcome a broader range of topics.

Comment: Thanks guys. If there's no good SE site for this then that's also an answer. Please post as a full answer so I can accept :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to identify the song first, then you could try your luck on [Music Fans](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com). They have [`identify-this-song`](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-song) tag. Consider reading [What should I do to improve my identification question?](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/q/350) to improve the chance for your question to get answered.

As for the language in the song... looks like [they also accept language identification in a strict sense](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/search?q=language).

At the very least, you could try asking to identify the song first, with a bonus question for identifying the language.